# Проблема с ListView.setAdapter();

Tags: android, listview

Добрый день! Я решил написать приложение-плеер, которое сканирует устройство, добавляет треки в плейлист, и по нажатию кнопки открывает таковой. Но возникла проблема: при нажатии на кнопку "Плейлист" выходит ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException, указывающая на ListView, который определён. 
Вот код:

---

```
public ArrayAdapter mAdapter;
public ListView mListView;
    private static final String[] EXTENSIONS = { ".mp3", ".wav", ".ogg", ".mus", ".aac" };
public List<String> trackNames;
public List<String> trackArtworks;
```

---

```
public String[] getTracks()
    {
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) 
            || Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))
        {
            path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
            String[] temp = path.list();
            return temp;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SD-карта не может быть прочитана или повреждена", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addTracks(String[] temp)
    {
        if (temp != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            {
                if (trackChecker(temp[i]))
                {
                    trackNames.add(temp[i]);
                    trackArtworks.add(temp[i].substring(0, temp[i].length() - 4));
                                    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listsong_screen);
                                    ArrayAdapter mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.listsong_item, trackNames);
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Загружено " + Integer.toString(trackNames.size()) + " треков", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean trackChecker(String trackToTest)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < EXTENSIONS.length; j++)
        {
            if (trackToTest.contains(EXTENSIONS[j]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void loadTrack()
    {
        if (mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            dispose();
        }
        if (trackNames.size() > 0)
        {
            loadMusic();
        }
    }
```

---

```
Button playlist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playlistbutton);
playlist.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(this) {
public void onClick(View v) {
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter)
}
});
```

Comment: Очевидно, что *mListView* на момент нажатия на кнопку равен *null*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Закоментируйте mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter). Не вылетает, тогда дело в этой строчке. Потом проверить на mAdapter!=null и т.д. А вообще, по-моему, лучше сначала установить адаптер(инициированный, но пустой), а потом при добавлении данных notifyDataSetChanged(). А по кнопке не устанавливать адаптер, а запускать обновление списка.
На момент щелчка ведь не понятно, запускали вы уже addTracks, где, как я понимаю, адаптер инициализируется, и отработала ли эта функция.
Самое простое, по клику: {getTracks(); mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}, тогда все должно работать, но так как все в гуях, может тормозить.

Сейчас перечитала вопрос.

> и по нажатию кнопки открывает таковой.

Ну так и делайте по нажатию именно это: добавляйте список в разметку, изменяйте видимость, инвалидэйтитесь и т.д. Можете, опять же, запускать обновление, если список во время действия программы может меняться. Устанавливать адаптер всякий раз это плохо, имхо.

Answer (score 3):

Как написано в комментарии во время нажатия на кнопку вызывается метод `onClick`. Внутри него у объекта `mListView` вызывается метод `setAdapter()`. Скорее всего на данный момент `mListView` просто непроинициализирован и компилятор выбрасывает исключение `NullPointerException`

Решением является инициализация объекта `mListView` посредством:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_myList);
```

Где `lv_myList` - это id контролла из xml

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_myList"
            ......
    />
```

Произвести инициализацию желательно в начале метода `onCreate` (там же где и инициализируется кнопка)

Comment: Попробовал сделать это, но всё равно выкидывает исключение nullpointerexception
Возможно дело в строке mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter)? Может ли ListView поставить в качестве адаптера ArrayAdapter<String>? И ещё: этот класс наследуется от Activity, a не от ListActivity.